# Too slow for converting to tf.constant when list contains 1000000 elems

Tags: tensorflow

What is the best way to do the training. That's too slow! And I don't know why it is that slow.

```
samples_all = tf.constant(samples_all)//more than 1000000 elems
labels_all = tf.constant(labels_all)
[sample, label] = tf.train.slice_input_producer([samples_all, labels_all])
```

The samples_all contains more than 1000000 string elems which represent the image paths. The first two lines in the code take too long to execute.

Comment: please add some more details to your question. seems incomplete to me.

Comment: @psyco thank you for replay, I've changed the question.

Comment: @keyur9779 What do you mean? Did you send the message to the wrong   person?

Comment: 1000000 is too large to use for a constant, you should instead use a variable and initialize it with `samples_all` using `var.assign` and `feed_dict`

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Ok, I will give it a try, thank you!

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov It doesn't work out, I changed the constant to the Variable. It still took too much time.

Comment: how are you creating/initializing your variable?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov just like tf.Variable(x). x is the list

Comment: ok, that's slow because tf.Variable(x) has to convert `x` to tensor so it's the same as `tf.Variable(tf.constant(x))`

Answer (score 0):

Below an example of loading 2M strings into string variable which takes less than 1 second on my MacBook. Variables are more efficient for large constants than `tf.constant` which are inlined in the graph. Note that there's also `tf.string_input_producer` which can handle large lists of strings without loading them all into TensorFlow memory.

```
n = 2000000
string_list = np.asarray(["string"]*n);

sess = tf.Session()
var_input = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string, shape=(n,))
var = tf.Variable(var_input)

start = time.time()
# var.initializer is equivalent to var.assign(var_input).op
sess.run(var.initializer, feed_dict={var_input: string_list})
elapsed = time.time()-start
rate = n*6./elapsed/10**6    
print("%.2f MB/sec"%(rate,))  # => 15.13 MB/sec
```

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try